# Gracefully finish for-loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, exception

I have a code inside a large for-loop in Python; I want to stop the running using Ctrl + C, but before stopping the execution, finish the current loop.

I'm aware of the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception, but I can't figure out how to allow the code to finish the current loop before stopping. So if I have this code, I should always print the `i` before the code stops.

```py
import time
import sys 

for i in range(1000):
    try:
        time.sleep(10)
        print(i)
    except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
        """
        allow to wait the remaining time and print i
        without duplicating the print(i) code
        """
        sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: This question has already been asked a few times on other forums. Check out this guide: https://newbedev.com/how-to-terminate-loop-gracefully-when-ctrl-c-was-pressed-in-python

Comment: I see now how to make it work, thanks!